# Set focus in the shadow dom using web components

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I try to set the focus on a node using my web component.

My web component is using shadow dom.

```
class MySelect extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();

    var template = document.getElementById('select-template').content;

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open', delegatesFocus: true });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

    this.selectNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.test-select__select');
    this.iconNode = this.selectNode.getElementsByClassName('test-select__select-icon')[0];
    this.menuNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.test-select__menu');

    this.value = null;
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.classList.add('cegid-select');
    this.#closeOptions();
    this.selectNode.addEventListener('click', this.#openOptions.bind(this));
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[attrName.replace('data-', '')] = newValue;
    }
  }

  set _value(option) {
    this.value = option.value;
    this.selectNode.getElementsByClassName('test-select__select-text')[0].textContent = option.label;
  }

  set options(options) {
    var menuNode = this.menuNode,
        menuItemNode;

    options.forEach((option) => {
      menuItemNode = document.createElement('div');
      menuItemNode.classList.add('test-select__menu-item');
      menuItemNode.textContent = option.label;
      menuItemNode.addEventListener('click', this.#selectOption.bind(this, option));
      menuNode.append(menuItemNode);
    });

    this._value = options[0];
  }


  #openOptions() {
    this.#focus();

    if (this.isOpen) {
      this.#closeOptions();
    } else {
      this.menuNode.style.display = 'block';
      this.isOpen = true;
    }
  }


  #closeOptions() {
    this.menuNode.style.display = 'none';
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  #selectOption(option) {
    this._value = option;

    this.dispatchEvent(
      new window.UIEvent('change',  {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        composed: true
      })
    );

    this.#closeOptions();
  }

  focus() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.test-select__select')
      .focus();
  }

  #focus() {
    this.focus();
  }
}

customElements.define('my-select', MySelect);
```

The issue is on the function `#focus()`, when after the execution I try to read the current active element, it return `null`.

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: There's no definition of the `select-template` so it's hard to tell what's going on. However, try removing the `delegatesFocus`. You might be using it wrong. Again, hard to tell because the code is incomplete.